# Validar formulario html con usuario para enviar a URL especifica dinamica usando base de Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, url, google-hoja-de-cálculo, cuenta-usuario

Tengo un formulario que valida el usuario con contraseña en una hoja de sheets de google y direcciona a una URL, pero necesito que una vez validado el usuario me envie a una direccion URL escrita en el mismo sheet en la siguiente columna, de tal forma que cuando un usuario se registre el formulario le abra la pagina especial escrita para ese usuario. Es decir si el login fue correcto entonces que me envie a mi URL.

En mi actual codigo el formulario me envia a una URL fija escrita en el codigo, quiero que sea dinamica.
Creo que solamente me hace falta una funcion del lado del codigo GS que busque la URL dependiendo del usuario para poder sustituir la URL fija del lado del cliente en el HTML. Les dejo el codigo completo y espero su ayuda.

la tabla en donde se aloja el usuario y contraseña (y de donde se tomará la URLL) es muy simple donde en donde los datos se alamacenan de la siguiente forma: En la Columna 0 (columna "A") se almacena el usarname, en la 1 el password y en la columna 2 la dirección URL El arreglo que necesito es que la web app busque que el usuario y la contraseña coincidan para posteriormente buscar en la columna 2 la URL que corresponda a dicho nombre de usuario.

Aquí el codigo GS:

```
 function doGet(e) {
 var x = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
 var y = x.evaluate();
 var z = y.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
 return z;}

 function checkLogin(username, password) {
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vpJ20I5eJb5GNL84nVx5VqXwbTLMYYxNh0VaOxkl0L8/edit#gid=0';
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
 var getLastRow =  webAppSheet.getLastRow();
 var found_record = '';
 for(var i = 1; i <= getLastRow; i++){
 if(webAppSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == username && 
 webAppSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue()== password){
 found_record = 'TRUE';}}
 if(found_record == ''){
 found_record = 'FALSE';}

 return found_record;}

 function AddRecord(usernamee, passwordd, email, phone) {
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vpJ20I5eJb5GNL84nVx5VqXwbTLMYYxNh0VaOxkl0L8/edit#gid=0';
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
 webAppSheet.appendRow([usernamee,passwordd,email,phone]);}
```

Aquí el codigo HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <base target="_top">
 <script>
 function AddRow(){
 var usernamee = document.getElementById("usernamee").value;
 var passwordd = document.getElementById("passwordd").value;
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
 if (usernamee==""|| passwordd==""|| email==""|| phone=="") {
 return false;}
  else {
  google.script.run.AddRecord(usernamee,passwordd,email,phone);
  document.getElementById("page2_id1").className = "page2_id1-off";
  document.getElementById("page3_id1").className = "page3_id1";}}

  function LoginUser(){
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
{
  if(output == 'TRUE')
  {
     var url1 = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
     var winRef = window.open(url1);
     winRef ? google.script.host.close() : window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('url').href = url1;}}
     else if(output == 'FALSE'){
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Usuario o contraseña invalida!"; }  }).checkLogin(username, password);}

 function function1(){
 document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_class1-off";
 document.getElementById("page2_id1").className = "page2_id1";}

 function function3(){ 
 document.getElementById("page3_id1").className = "page3_id1-off";
 document.getElementById("page1_id1").className = "page1_id1";}

 </script>
 <style>


 /*page1*/
 .page1_class1-off{
 display: none;}


 /*page2*/
 .page2_class1{
 display: none;}

 .page2_id1-off{
 display:none;}

 /*page3*/
 .page3_class1{
 display:none;}
 .page3_id1-off{
 display:none;}


 input[type=text]:hover{
 border-bottom:2px solid black;}
 input[type=number]:hover{
 border-bottom:2px solid black;}
 input[type=password]:hover{
 border-bottom:2px solid black;}

 .user{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 border: 8px solid black;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;}

 /*the head/*/
 .user::before{
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 background: black;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 left: calc(50% - 11px);
 top: 10px;}

 /*the body*/
 .user::after{
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width:50px;
 height:40px;
 background: black;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 left: calc(50% - 24px);
 top: 39px;}

 </style>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
 <br><br>
 <!--page1-->
 <center>
 <div class="page1_class1" id="page1_id1" style="background:#E3E0DF;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 400px;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 30px;padding-left: 30px;padding-right: 30px;"> 
 <h1>Acceso a Panel de Empresa</h1>
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Usuario" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;background:#FEFEFE"/><br>
 <br>
 <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/>
 <br><span id="errorMessage" style="color: red" ></span><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Inicio" onclick="LoginUser()"  style="float: center;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 3px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight:bold;" /><br>
 <br><br></br>
 <b>¿ Aún no tienes cuenta ?</b><br></br><input type="button" onClick="function1()" value="Crea una Cuenta" style="margin-top: 10px;font-weight:bold;" />
 </div>

 <!--page2-->
 <div class="page2_class1" id="page2_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 300px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 30px;padding-left: 30px;padding-right: 30px;background:#F2F8B1">
 <h1>Crea una Cuenta</h1>
 <input type="text" id="usernamee" placeholder="Nombre Usuario" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
 <br>
 <input type="password" id="passwordd" placeholder="Crea Contraseña" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size: 0.9;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;" /><br>
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;"/><br>
 <br>
 <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Teléfono celular." style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none;outline: none; text-align: center;font-size:0.9em ;width: 50%;font-weight:bold;" /><br><br><br></br>
 <b style="color:red;">La contraseña debe contener letras y números. No funcionará sin letras y números.</b><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Crear" onclick="AddRow()" style="float: right;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 1px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight:bold;" />
 <br><br></br>
 </div>

 <!--page3-->
 <div class="page3_class1" id="page3_id1" style="background:none;border:2px solid gray;border-radius: 20px;width: 250px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;background:#7CF76C"><center>
 <h2> Su cuenta ha sido creada satisfactoriamente. Ingrese a su cuenta</h2>
 <input type="submit"  onClick="function3()" value="Login" style="font-weight:bold;"><br>
 </div> 


 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Título = Idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = detalles.

Comment: No dejes código completo, deja un [mcve] específico al problema que tienes. Dices "Creo que solamente me hace falta una funcion del lado del codigo GS que busque la URL dependiendo del usuario para poder sustituir la URL fija del lado del cliente en el HTML." así que tu código debería mostrar lo que has intentado para escribir esa función que te falta. Una de las cosas que tienes que decidir es la estructura de los datos, en otras palabras, (¿ vas a usar un array de arrays, un array de objetos o un objeto?) También es recomendable incluir una breve descripción de sus esfuerzos de búsqueda.

Comment: Inicio en programación, aún no sé que arreglo necesito por eso la publicación. Estoy buscando una funcion que me ayude a buscar la celda especifica según el usuario que ejecuta el login y que me pueda escribir la URL en la variable: var url1 = 'https://stackoverflow.com';. Tienes alguna idea de como ?

Comment: Las preguntas en este sitio deben ser específicas. Considerando esto podrías centrar tu pregunta en el "arreglo" que necesitas, por otro lado si los datos ya están en una hoja de cálculo deberías incluir datos de ejemplo en la forma que los has dispuesto en la hoja de cálculo (¿se trata de una tabla simple, es una tabla de doble entrada, ...?)

Comment: Hola @ruben gracias por tu respuesta, la tabla es simple donde en donde los datos se alamacen de la siguiente forma: En la Columna 0 (columna "A") se almacena el usarname, en la 1 el password y en la columna 2 la url. El arreglo que necesito es que la web app busque que el usuario y contraseña coincidan para posteriormente buscar en la columna 2 la URL que corresponde a dicho username.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar a esta toda la información relevante.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que el return de tu función checkLogin() sea un objeto que contenga si lo encontró o no y aparte el url (que entiendo que se encuentra en la columna junto al usuario y contraseña)

```
    let url1 = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()
    ...
    let obj1 { 
     found_record: true, 
     url: url1
    }
```

Comment: Tengo 3 perguntas:

Comment: 1.- La variable       let url1 = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()  la anexo en el codigo GS como variable global o dentro de cual funcion ? 2.-

Comment: 2.- La variable          let obj1 { found_record: true,  url: url1 }        la anexo en el index, en que parte ?

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia podrías insertalo para hacer una prueba. De cualquier forma forma agradezco mucho tu tiempo para resolver este problema.

Comment: Defines el url en cuanto tu ciclo for encuentra el usuario y contraseña (dentro de tu primer if

`found_record = 'TRUE';
url1 = webAppSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()`

Comment: Estarías regresando un objeto en vez de un booleano, por lo que "output" tiene esos dos valores que le diste (found record y url1);
En el script de tu index modifica el `if (output == TRUE)` a `if (output.found_record == TRUE)`
Y la asignación del valor de url1 a  `url1 = output.url1`